# Spring binding values in a Map

Tags: java, spring, binding, spring-mvc

Is there a way to Spring bind values in a map?

For instance, I have a `Map<String,String>` and I want to spring bind specific values in it. 
The user will type something into a input element, and the value of that input element will get bound to the value associated with a specific key in the map.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with `[...]` syntax. The `Map` itself, however, should be a property of the command object:

```
public class Form {
    private Map<String, String> values = ...;
    ...
}
```

Then you submit a form with the input field named `values['foo']`, i.e. with Spring form tags it would be a `path`:

```
<form:input path = "values['foo']" />
```

or `name` in plain HTML:

```
<input name = "values['foo']" type = "text" />
```

Comment: Is that the PHP way of doing it? I'm working with Java and Velocity so that Syntax doesn't work.

Comment: Is values['foo'] the same as values.get('foo') in your syntax?

Comment: @stevebot values['foo'] is the Expression Language equivalent of values.get('foo')

Comment: @stevebot: `values['foo']` is a path in Spring MVC terms (i.e. a name of HTTP parameters). Given this path Spring sets the value that can be accessed as `values.get("foo")`.

Comment: Map String values can be bind in JSP. Can integer values of map/object be binded?

Comment: According to the HTML spec, the '[' and ']' characters are not allowed in the name attribute! I'm not sure how different browsers treat this under different DOCTYPEs but maybe this isn't a good idea.

Comment: @IcedDante: where do you see that in the HTML spec? I can't find it.